# Problem with two identical Google+1 buttons on web page

Tags: social-networking

I have two Google+1 buttons on the same page. Button's codes are identical. But there are only one button showed on the page - the first button. The second one doesn't appears on the page

Does anyone have the same problem?
Thanks for your answers!

Comment: Coudl you provide us with more details? You could simply have an error in you css or wherever else

Comment: I will try to place them one by one to exclude probability of css problems...

Comment: There is div id="___plusone_0" wich has iframe inside first button and is empty inside second button... This is not css problem. I think the problem is that id must be unique. But in my situation there are two same ids

Comment: id's must be unique, indeed. You could try giving the 2nd div another id but copying the properties of the 1st with javascript

Comment: I think I must use gapi.plusone.render(container, {"size": "standard", "count": "true"});